# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when clicking back button in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, exc-bad-access

I have a strange problem with back button in NavigationController. If I use parser and then I click Back button, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _lbRouteNum.text = self.RouteNumber;

    self.InfoTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.InfoTableView.delegate = self;

    lbCity = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    //    [lbCity addObject:@"sdfsdfsdfsdfsd"];

    NSData * XMLData = [self.response dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:XMLData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:      (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary  *)attributeDict
{

      if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Citys"])
      {
        //do something
      }
}
```

If I comment this

```
//NSData * XMLData = [self.response dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
//NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:XMLData];
//[parser setDelegate:self];
//[parser parse];
```

and for test uncomment this

```
    [lbCity addObject:@"sdfsdfsdfsdfsd"];
```

all working good.

If I change parsing code for test on:

```
      if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Citys"])
      {
        [lbCity addObject:@"sdfsdfsdfsdfsd"];
      }
```

2 times all open an back ok on 3rd when I click Back button App crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (

Solution:
I move to ARC and all problems gone. Thanks.

Comment: Have you made sure that `self.response` is set properly before calling this? You may want to put your xml parsing code inside of a setter method on `self.response`.

Comment: I try to change parsing code on [lbCity addObject:@"sdfsdfsdfsdfsd"]; and on 3rd time my app crash O_O, 2 times all ok on 3rd I click back and app crash ( response is a property what I get from previous View, and have value, parser working in table I see what I want but when click Back app crash. What do you mean - "You may want to put your xml parsing code inside of a setter method", how I can do this ?

Comment: How I understand I need parse my xml in ViewDidLoad but I not understand why.

Comment: I try don't use XMLParser, and have same problems (

Comment: I remove all @property and use global variables, this is not good but all working without problems.

Comment: No, my happy be not very long, I add code of all my class to question.